# How to get hibernate to return entity even if entity doesn't exist in database

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, null, entity

Ok, im not sure how to put this. But here goes.

say i have a database with the tables movie and user_movie, movie holds information on any given movie, and user_movie holds information on the users relationship to the movie.

So, when a user sets the value "watched" on a given movie, then this results in a table record in user_movie. however, if a user doesn't set any movies as watched, then this would mean that the no movies have been watched and no records are set. so there is this logic already in place. (Now i could always have just created a default record for each and every user times the number of movies. but this wouldn't be very effective.)

so when i try to create a query like, fetch me all movies that the user hasn't watched. that should return me a list of ALL the movies in the database. however, since user_media doesn't contain any records, it would actually give me an empty list.

so is there a solution i could use here?

Is it possible to get hibernate to return a "default" entity in the event that the entity doesn't exist? or in the event of a "left join" and the joined value is NULL can i return a default value?

my current backend is mysql. maybe i could create a custom function to deal with this problem?

EDIT

user_media can also hold values like acquired (true,false), wishlisted (true,false), emotion (LOVE,HATE,NULL)

A requirement for my solution is that i get a list of user_media joined with movie. Therefore user_media can't be NULL.

Comment: How do you get a list of all the movies a user hasn't watched in the situation where the user has watched some?  There should be a single query that can handle both situations.

Comment: something like this maybe? from Movie where id in (select movie_id from UserMedia where watched = false and user_id = x), watched is just one of the values in the user -> movie relationship, there are also other values like, acquired (true,false), emotion (LOVE,HATE,NULL), wishlisted (true,false)

Answer (score 4):

This query in `MySQL` will return you the list of movies user `1` hasn't watched:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    movie
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  movie_id
        FROM    user_movie
        WHERE   user_id = 1
                AND watched = 1
        )
```

Create a `UNIQUE` index (or, better, a `PRIMARY KEY`) on `user_movie (user_id, movie_id)` for this to work fast.

A test case:

```
CREATE TABLE movie (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE user_movie (user_id INT NOT NULL, movie_id INT NOT NULL, watched BOOL, PRIMARY KEY (user_id, movie_id));

INSERT
INTO    movie
VALUES
        (1, 'Titanic'),
        (2, 'Office Space'),
        (3, 'Surf Nazis Must Die');

INSERT
INTO    user_movie
VALUES  (1, 1, FALSE),
        (1, 2, TRUE);

SELECT  *
FROM    movie
WHERE   id NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  movie_id
        FROM    user_movie
        WHERE   user_id = 1
                AND watched = 1
        );
```

This will return

```
1, 'Titanic'
3, 'Surf Nazis Must Die'
```

`Titanic` is returned because the user explicitly told he didn't watch it, `Surf Nazis Must Die` is returned because the user didn't insert a record for it.

Comment: this would actually only give me the list of movies that the user has NO relationship to. by no relationship i actually mean the user hasn't performed any action on the movie, and therefore there is no record of it in user_media. this example would not include the movies that a user actually have set "watched" to false

Comment: the "AND watched = 1" would beg to differ.

Comment: @netbrain: this will return all movies for which the user has not set `watched = 1`, either by inserting record with other value for `watched` (like `0`), or by not inserting the record at all. Isn't it what you wanted?

Comment: @Quassnoi, yes this is what i asked, but this was a simplified problem, and it does work in this case, but not in all my cases.

Comment: @Don Roby well, take this case for instance. say that we expand user_movie with acquired as well and not just watched. so we now have the two fields watched and acquired. now i would like to fetch all the movies that user1 has as acquired, and that user1 and user2 hasn't set as watched.

Comment: i could always create a new query for this case that would look something like this: from Movie where id not in (select media from UserMedia where (user.id = 1 or user.id = 2) and watched = true) and id in (select media from UserMedia where user.id = 1 and acquired = true) but how can i make a more flexible query that can change in accordance to what the user want to filter on?

Comment: Another problem i have with this solution, is that i would like to fetch a list of the type user_media and left join movie. that way i can keep data on the users relationship to the movie list. thats why i really would like a magical performance effective way of giving me a "default value" or default user_media record when this is NULL or doesn't exist.

Comment: by the way. thank you for taking the time to ponder this problem with me :)

Comment: @netbrain: please post a sample recordset and desired output of your query